# Validating check box and input

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, validation

i have a form that includes several text inputs and checkboxes (the checkboxes comes from a DB), so... i know how to validate them separetly but i need to validate them together, the way i'm doing this only validate checkboxes, i know why its happening but i don't know how to write the right way... ¿can you help me? here is the code:

```
<form action="sendreq.php" name="contact" onsubmit="return valida_frm(this)" method="post">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" />

                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="text"/><!-- And Severeal inputs then the checkboxes-->

<?php $list3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20"); 
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($list3)){ ?>


                <input id="product" name="product[]" class="label" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row->name?>"><label class="label"><?php echo $row->name?></label>                    

                <?php }?>
```

The Validation doesn't work fine its evident why, i just need the right way to write and unify the return of the alert:

```
function valida_frm(form){
var alerta="Ooops:\n";
if (form.name.value == "") {alerta+="Name.\n";} 
if (form.email.value == "") {alerta+="Email.\n";}

for(var i = 0; i < form.product.length; i++){ 
    if(form.product[i].checked)return true;} 
    alert('Oooops'); 
    return false;   

if (alerta!="Error:\n"){
    alert(alerta);  
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}   
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The problem is in the way that you're accessing the form checkbox element. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call a field for "name" and then test form.name since it already has a .name

Then test form["product[]"] and not form.product - you cannot have id="product" since ID has to be unique!
I suggest you give `id="product<?echo $somecounter; ?>" />...<label for="product<? echo $somecounter; ?>">...</label>`

Also test against Error (or nothing as in my suggesion) and not Oops

Also more issues fixed

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/H5wFz/)

```
function valida_frm(form){
  var alerta="";
  if (form.name.value == "") {alerta+="Name.\n";}  // Please use FullName or such
  if (form.email.value == "") {alerta+="Email.\n";}
  var chks = form["product[]"],
      checked = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) { 
    if(chks[i].checked) {
      checked = true;
      break;
    }
  } 
  if (!checked) {
    alerta+='Product.\n'; 
  }  
  if (alerta){
    alert("Error:\n"+alerta);  
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: done! thank you so much! the id and name thing was just for illustrative porpouses, the original names were not relevant... the real form is too long, in spanish... anyway i was using that id for a little styling, but i switched to class, you are so right in what you say! thanks for your advices!